# count total and positive samples by group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this;

```
df <- data.frame(concentration=c(0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,4,4,6,6,6),
             result=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1))
```

I want to count the total number of results for each concentration level.
I want to count the number of positive samples for each concentration level.
And I want to create a new dataframe with concentration level, total results, and number positives.

```
conc pos_c total_c
0    0     4
2    1     4
4    1     2
6    3     3
```

This is what I've come up with so far using plyr;

```
c <- count(df, "concentration")
r <- count(df, "concentration","result")
names(c)[which(names(c) == "freq")] <- "total_c"
names(r)[which(names(r) == "freq")] <- "pos_c"
cbind(c,r)

  concentration total_c concentration pos_c
1             0       4             0     0
2             2       4             2     1
3             4       2             4     1
4             6       3             6     3
```

Repeating concentration column. I think there is probably a way better/easier way to do this I'm missing. Maybe another library. I'm  not sure how to do this in R and it's relatively new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a group by `sum`.  Using `tidyverse`, we group by 'concentration (`group_by`), then `summarise` to get the two columns - 1) `sum` of the logical expression (`result > 0`), 2) number of rows (`n()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(conc = concentration) %>% 
  summarise(pos_c = sum(result > 0), # in the example just sum(result) 
                    total_c = n())
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   conc pos_c total_c
#  <dbl> <int>   <int>
#1     0     0       4
#2     2     1       4
#3     4     1       2
#4     6     3       3
```

---

Or using `base R` with `table` and `addmargins`

```
addmargins(table(df), 2)[,-1]
```